# Long polling: Max Pool size reached

Tags: mysql, ajax, vb.net, long-polling

I'm using long polling in my website to check for any new data in MySQL database and then updating the ui,
actually if the website is up for longer than +- one hour the website just broke up by giving the following error:

```
 500 {"Message":"error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.","StackTrace":"   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at VisualReservation._Default.getSale() in C:\\Users\\imytyuk\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\VisualReservation\\VisualReservation\\Default.aspx.vb:line 109","ExceptionType":"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException"}
```

So it seems that there are too many connections to the database and it just get broken..
Actually the error is thrown by the following method that is called from long polling

```
function getTavoli(data_tavoli, salaSelect, pooling) {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SetTavoli",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: moment(data_tavoli).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var ingiorno = $('#ingiorno').val();
            var fngiorno = $('#fngiorno').val();
            var insera = $('#insera').val();
            var fnsera = $('#fnsera').val();
            ingiorno = ingiorno.split(":")[0];
            fngiorno = fngiorno.split(":")[0];
            insera = insera.split(":")[0];
            fnsera = fnsera.split(":")[0];
            if ($('#titleTurni').attr('data-turno') == "giorno") {
                Range = ingiorno * 4
                Fine = (fngiorno * 4) + 1;
                orainizio = ingiorno;
                orafine = fngiorno;
            } else {
                Range = insera * 4
                Fine = (fnsera * 4) + 1;
                orainizio = insera;
                orafine = fnsera;
            }

            data = r.d;
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (pooling) {
                if (JSON.stringify(data) === prevData) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    recreateTabs();
                    prevData = JSON.stringify(data);
                }
            }



            $('#listBodyMobile').empty();
            $('#bodyGiorno').empty();
            $('#bodySera').empty();

            getInfo(data_tavoli);

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                   // doing all stuff with items
                });

            });

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrow) {
            console.log(xhr.status + " " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

The polling is called in the following way

```
poolingTav = setInterval(() => {
    getTavoli(new Date($("#day").attr('data-giorno')), $("#titleSale").attr('data-numsala'), true);
}, 50000)
```

While the SetTavoli in the server side looks like the following

```
<WebMethod()>
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
    Public Shared Function SetTavoli(ByVal data As String) As String


        Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "CONNSTRING"

        DeleteSTB(con)

        Dim strSql As String = "QUERY"

        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        con.Open()
        Dim sqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strSql, con)
            Dim sqlDad As New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
            sqlDad.Fill(dtb)
            con.Dispose()
            dtb.Columns(0).ColumnName = "data"
            dtb.Columns(1).ColumnName = "orain"
            dtb.Columns(2).ColumnName = "oraout"
            dtb.Columns(3).ColumnName = "numtav"
            dtb.Columns(4).ColumnName = "numcop"
            dtb.Columns(5).ColumnName = "email"
            dtb.Columns(6).ColumnName = "tel"
            dtb.Columns(7).ColumnName = "note"
            dtb.Columns(8).ColumnName = "nome"
            dtb.Columns(9).ColumnName = "id"
            dtb.Columns(10).ColumnName = "stato"

        Return Json(dtb)
    End Function
```

So i was wondering what i'm doing wrong and how i could fix that issue still by using long polling...

To the website there will be connected lot of users with their own account and will be accessing their own databases..

Comment: If you use the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement for `con`, that will make sure that the connection is always disposed of, even if something goes wrong.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i gonna try it, but just can't understand why in that way the connection is not disposed out even if i check Server Connections in MySQL for each request from polling is created one connection that is not disposed out..

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement